# C# select specific row from HashSet

Tags: c#, .net

I have a  `HashSet<string> DirectoryHolding = new HashSet<string>();`

How do I say I want indexOf[1] without a for statement?

Comment: Before answering could you tell us why do you want to access a specific position of an hashset? 
It looks like you may want a dictionary or a simple List, instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

```
using System.Linq;

DirectoryHolding.ElementAt(1);
```

Comment: While this avoids writing "for" in your code, it nonetheless executes a loop to find the element at the given position; this answer also fails to note that an element's position will change as the hash set increases its capacity.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` doesn't preserve primary order of items, therefore it doesn't have index access. Internally `HashSet` is hashtable whose values are also keys.

Comment: I already did.  I was delayed by writing a complaint about the downvote on my own answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote but technically you're correct however there is functionality to achieve the same goal

Answer (score 1):

Use `DirectoryHolding.ElementAt(1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without a for statement (you can do it with linq, but that iterates the set, even if you never write "for" in your code).

In any event, be warned that sets are unordered.  That means that the position of any element of the set may change.  Given the current implementation, the position will change whenever the HashSet has to increase its capacity.